# Modify View after Binding Command Executes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `DataGrid` and two buttons. Pressing the first button will call a command that populates my DataGrid from a database table using a `DataTable`. The second button will apply some logic and eventually remove the data from the database table. My problem is, after I select the second button, the DataGrid does not update and still shows the row that do not exist in the database anymore. Here is my setup:

Button1 (Populates the DataGrid):

```
<Button Content="Load Data" Command="{Binding FillMyDataTableCommand}"/>
```

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">
```

Button2 (Applies logic and the data should not be in the table anymore):

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid}"</Button>
```

On selecting button2, my ViewModel takes care of the logic, after the logic I would like to update the datagrid to display the changes to the table with:

```
myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

I can not do this in the ViewModel as that would violate MVVM as it should know nothing about the view. I tried a workaround by adding to the code behind for the button with a click command hoping it would execute after the binding command. However it executed first:

Button2 (attempt):

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid}" click="button_click_Refresh"</Button>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTable is not updating DataGrid after clearing and refilling data. MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215919/datatable-is-not-updating-datagrid-after-clearing-and-refilling-data-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this issue as well.

I came up with two solutions that worked for me:

- Changed the data type for the ItemSource of my DataGrid to ObservableCollection, which updates the UI when the collection changes.
- To overwrite my ItemSource when the data needs to change. For example, assigning a new DataTable as the ItemSource when I want to retrieve different data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model where the `MyDataTable` property is defined should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.

You could then modify the `DataView` of the `DataTable` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `MyDataTable` property in your view model to refresh the `DataGrid` in the view:

```
//update datatable...
//and raise the event when you're done:
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyDataTable)));
```

Comment: The `DataTable` I access is a part of my `DataSet` which uses SQL queries in an .xsd file. My `ViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` however, I am not sure where the `PropertyChanged?` line goes.

Comment: @TheGreatZab: In the setter of `MyDataTable` for example.